# Highlight search results in ListView

Tags: android, string, listview

I have a `ListView` with `String`s. With the below code I can highlight search results, but the user must type the words to search case sensitive. **How can I implement a none - case sensitive highlighting of search results for example like the native Android Contact search?**

Here is my code for Highlighting. I extend the `ArrayAdapter` and implement customized filter to get the string to search. In the `getView` method I check if my `String` in ListView contains the `prefixString` and highlight it.

```
public class HighlightListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> objects;
    final Object mLock =new Object();
    private ArrayList<String> mOriginalValues;
    private ArrayFilter filter;
    private String prefixString;
    public AuthorsListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }



    class ViewHolder{
        TextView author;

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
        // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.author_list_item, null);
            holder.author =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.author_list_item_text);
            v.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        }


         final String author = objects.get(position);        
        if (author != null) {


        holder.author.setText(author);
        if(prefixString !=null && prefixString.length()>1){
            String s =  author;



        **if(s.contains(prefixString)){
            String rep = s.replace(prefixString,    "<b><font color=#2825A6>"+ prefixString+ "</font></b>");
            holder.author.setText(Html.fromHtml(rep));
        }** // higlight 



        }

            }

        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return objects.size();
    }



     @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(filter == null){
            filter =new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }



    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.objects.get(position);
    }



    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(objects);
                    }
                }

                if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                    ArrayList<String> list;
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        list = new ArrayList<String>(mOriginalValues);
                    }
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                } else {
                    **prefixString = prefix.toString();** // get string to search

                    ArrayList<String> values;
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        values = new ArrayList<String>(mOriginalValues);
                    }

                    final int count = values.size();
                    final ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        final String value = values.get(i);
                        final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase();

                        // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                        if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                            newValues.add(value);
                        } else {
                            final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                            final int wordCount = words.length;

                            // Start at index 0, in case valueText starts with space(s)
                            for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                                if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                    newValues.add(value);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    results.values = newValues;
                    results.count = newValues.size();
                }

                return results;
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,  FilterResults results) {
                   objects = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                if (results.count > 0) {
                                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                               } else {
                                 notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                              }

            }

        };
    }
```

Comment: You can make both lowercase and then compare them. But your code is not working properly.

Comment: If i make both lowercase and compare them, i have to make a few letters to uppercase after i replaced it with the HTML code.. And that is complicated.. I can insure you that this code is working very well. Have you a better solution?

Comment: Calling member function of `String` instance rarely affects contents of string. You can use `s.toLowerCase()` without changing it's content. Lowercased string is returned.

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This what I use :

- Every occurence is replaced (not only prefix)
- Case and accent are ignored while searching but retained in the result.
- It uses directly `SpannableString`, which you can use in `setText()`. I believe it's more efficient than using an intermediate html step.

.

```
public static CharSequence highlight(String search, String originalText) {
    // ignore case and accents
    // the same thing should have been done for the search text
    String normalizedText = Normalizer.normalize(originalText, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "").toLowerCase();

    int start = normalizedText.indexOf(search);
    if (start < 0) {
        // not found, nothing to to
        return originalText;
    } else {
        // highlight each appearance in the original text
        // while searching in normalized text
        Spannable highlighted = new SpannableString(originalText);
        while (start >= 0) {
            int spanStart = Math.min(start, originalText.length());
            int spanEnd = Math.min(start + search.length(), originalText.length());

            highlighted.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(<background_color>), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            start = normalizedText.indexOf(search, spanEnd);
        }

        return highlighted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. this is a nice solution to highlight searched string in listViews!

Comment: nice job @bwt I searched a lot for this and finally I got your code useful

Comment: Could you please tell where exactly to use your method to get highlighted result? Tried to put inside my filter, but no luck. Please guide me with that.

Comment: Searched for this for hours. Beautifully executed. Can be used on EditText, TextView, etc... Ex: tvMyText.setText(highlightText(search, originalText));

Comment: in this method how to know how many search is found in originalText ?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is nice. But you can do it by a single line of code. What I've done in my case to avoid the case sensitive issue is:

```
Spannable sb = new SpannableString(originalText);
                    sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), originalText.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()),
                            originalText.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) + query.length(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
result.setText(sb);
```

Hope it might help!
Note: Here 'query' is the part of the string that you want to highlight.

Comment: query is the part of the string that you want to highlight.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple & Advanced Search Highlighting Example [Case Insensitive Order]**

**1.** ***Simple Search (Html):***

```
public static void setSearchTextHighlightSimpleHtml(TextView textView, String fullText, String searchText) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            fullText = fullText.replaceAll("(?i)(" + searchText + ")", "<span style=\"background-color:#FCFF48;\"><b><big><font color='#a10901'>$1</font></big></b></span>");
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fullText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        } else {
            fullText = fullText.replaceAll("(?i)(" + searchText + ")", "<b><big><font color='red'>$1</font></big></b>");
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fullText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        textView.setText(fullText);
    }
}
```

**2.** ***Simple Search (Spannable):***

```
public static void setSearchTextHighlightSimpleSpannable(TextView textView, String fullText, String searchText) {

    // highlight search text
    if (null != searchText && !searchText.isEmpty()) {

        SpannableStringBuilder wordSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder(fullText);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(searchText, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(fullText);
        while (m.find()) {

            int wordStart = m.start();
            int wordEnd = m.end();

            // Now highlight based on the word boundaries
            ColorStateList redColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{0xffa10901});
            TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, redColor, null);

            wordSpan.setSpan(highlightSpan, wordStart, wordEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            wordSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFCFF48), wordStart, wordEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            wordSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.25f), wordStart, wordEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        }

        textView.setText(wordSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    } else {
        textView.setText(fullText);
    }
}
```

**3.** ***Advanced Search (Spannable):***

```
public static void setAdvancedSearch(TextView textView, String fullText, String searchText) {

    if (searchText.length() == 0) {
        textView.setText(fullText);
        return;
    }

    final String searchBoundary = " \n()।.,;?-+!";
    char[] boundaries = searchBoundary.toCharArray();

    // highlight search text
    if (isNotEquals(searchText, boundaries)) {

        SpannableStringBuilder wordSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder(fullText);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(searchText, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(fullText);
        while (m.find()) {

            int wordStart = m.start();
            while (wordStart >= 0 && isNotEquals(fullText.charAt(wordStart), boundaries)) {
                --wordStart;
            }
            wordStart = wordStart + 1;

            int wordEnd = m.end();
            while (wordEnd < fullText.length() && isNotEquals(fullText.charAt(wordEnd), boundaries)) {
                ++wordEnd;
            }

            setWordSpan(wordSpan, wordStart, wordEnd);

        }

        textView.setText(wordSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    } else {
        textView.setText(fullText);
    }
}

private static boolean isNotEquals(char charAt, char[] boundaries) {
    return isNotEquals(String.valueOf(charAt), boundaries);
}

private static boolean isNotEquals(String searchText, char[] boundaries) {
    for (char boundary : boundaries) {
        boolean equals = searchText.equals(String.valueOf(boundary));
        if (equals) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static void setWordSpan(SpannableStringBuilder wordSpan, int wordStart, int wordEnd) {
    // Now highlight based on the word boundaries
    ColorStateList redColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{0xffa10901});
    TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, redColor, null);

    wordSpan.setSpan(highlightSpan, wordStart, wordEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    wordSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFCFF48), wordStart, wordEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    wordSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.25f), wordStart, wordEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your code

```
if(s.contains(prefixString)){
    String rep = s.replace(prefixString,    "<b><font color=#2825A6>"+ prefixString+ "</font></b>");
    holder.author.setText(Html.fromHtml(rep));
}
```

is not good. You should use `String.startsWith` to check if the start of `s` equals to `prefixString`. Your actual code works, but it checks presence of `prefixString` in `s`, but doesn't care about its position. 
For having case insensitive search, you can use `String.toLowerCase` or `String.toUpperCase` on both strings when checking presence of `prefixString`. Case will be ignored.

```
if(s.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefixString.toLowerCase())){
    String rep = "<b><font color=#2825A6>" + prefixString + "</font></b>" + s.substring(prefixString.length());
    holder.author.setText(Html.fromHtml(rep));
}
```

Comment: With your code and with my code too the uppercase Strings in s will never replaced with prefixString if prefixString does not contain the same uppercase chars. I give you an example: String s = "Johann Wolfgang von Goethe"; and  String prefixString = "wolf"; In your code and in my code too s.toLowerCase().contains(prefixString.toLowerCase()) return true because "wolf" is in the lowercase s.. But the s.replace method will not replace the prefixString. "wolf" willt not matched with "Wolf"..  Hope i had now explained my problem better. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ok, you're right. But you don't have to use replace. Look on my edit.

Comment: your code will still not working. i am sorry. i think i explained not good enough.

Comment: What errors do you get? In strings starting with `perfixString`, this should be working.

Comment: the substring methode is not defined for substring(String, int)... it only accepts ints.. : substring(int start, int end)

Comment: True. it should be `s.substring(prefixString.length())`. Is it working now?

Comment: user35443. Your solution returns always a String with lowercase  -> "Johann Wolfgang von Goethe" will highlighted but it appears in the listView as "johann wolfgang von goethe".. Thank you for your help. I think for highliting string in android BWTs  solution is the best way.

Comment: Ok. Can you post some screenshot?

Comment: I am sorry but i cant. If you look at your code you will understand it. String rep = "<b><font color=#2825A6>" + prefixString + "</font></b>" + s.substring(prefixString.length()); .. in my code prefixString is ALWAYS lowercase. Because of that  this code: "<b><font color=#2825A6>" + prefixString + "</font></b>" +  s.substring(prefixString.length()); will always return a lowercase String..

Comment: Hmm? Why is it ALWAYS lowercase?