# How to color some part of string in android?

Tags: android

I have implemented a search list
It outputs the matched strings from pattern in a given list view.
Now I want to color only that part of my string which matches the pattern.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16872945/1288725)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for spannable:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

Example:

```
SpannableString demotext = new SpannableString("All your base are belong to me");
// Make 'All' (chars 0 to 3) red
demotext.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 3, 0);
((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_disclaimer_title)).setText(demotext);
```

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring
http://eazyprogramming.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/spannable-string-in-android-url-span.html

Answer (score 0):

for color a part of your string you can do like this :

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

just after modify this.

Comment: String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Not working if I assign my string to text view which is in listview.